# how to ignore $ sign in value and sum

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark

This is how my csv data looks like:

```
TagNumber,DatePaid,TotalPaid
ABCD,11/5/2017,$101
EFGH,12/5/2017,$201
ABCD,15/5/2017,$501
```

I am creating a dataframe that will group the data by TagNumber, get Min and Max of DatePaid and sum TotalPaid.

This is how I am creating dataframe

```
valid_data = valid_data.select('TagNumber', from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('DatePaid', 'MM/dd/yyy')).alias('m_paiddDate'), "TotalPaid")\
        .groupBy("TagNumber") \
        .agg(F.min("DatePaid").alias("min_date"), F.max("DatePaid").alias("max_date"), F.count("TagNumber").alias("no_of_times_paid")) \
        .orderBy("no_of_times_paid", ascending=False)
```

When I add `F.sum("TotalPaid").alias("Total_Paid")` to aggregator, I get empty values for `Total_Paid` column as it is being treated as string due to `$` sign.

How do I get `sum` for `TotalPaid` column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this to convert `TotalPaid` to a numerical value (first remove the $ with regular expressions, then cast):

```py
valid_data = valid_data.withColumn(
    'TotalPaid', F.regexp_replace('TotalPaid','\$', '').cast('float')
)
```

Comment: I disagree, what if your monetary amounts include cents? In any case, the basic methodology works, the datatype for the cast can be changed as required

Comment: To represent financial data you should always use fixed precision numbers (i.e. `DecimalType`), never floating point numbers.